# PHP sqlite3 database dropdown menu using python eel

Tags: python, php, html, sql, eel

I am trying to printing values in dropdown menu. the values printing on console, but doesn't printing on html

here is my code:

```
<select>
<?php
  $db = new SQLite3('Clients.db');
  $results = $db->query("SELECT EPWNIMIA FROM Pelates");

  while($row = $results->fetchArray(SQLITE3_ASSOC))
  {
      $value = $row['EPWNIMIA'];
      echo "<option>$value</option>";
  }
?>

</select>
```

[image]

Comment: Is that snippet not working in a `.html` file? If so, suggest you "view element" and see what is rendered.